Please add the “Create tag info” button for users who do not have the Trusted User privilege
Currently when you arrive at an empty tag wiki, there is a bunch of text stating what a tag wiki is and encouraging you to create one.
If you are a Trusted User, then you will find a button at the bottom saying “Create Tag Info”. Users who are not Trusted Users will not see a button.
I think it is based on whether or not the user is a Trusted User as I only see the button on the site where I am a Trusted User.
(Registered) users who aren’t Trusted Users can still propose tag wikis, so it makes sense for there to be a similar button for them as well, perhaps saying “Propose” rather than “Create”. Could this be done?
Here are two screenshots highlighting this issue.
Link to the animated-png tag:
As seen by a non-trusted user:

Link to the hyperterminal tag:
As seen by a trusted user:


I can see two buttons: (1) in the text "The ????  tag has no usage guidance, can you [help us create it?]" where the text in brackets is the button and the "Help us edit this wiki" button when you hover over the tag below a question, for example. Are you referring to the info page of a tag? i.e. https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/animated-png/info

@PeterJames no button for creating a tag wiki visible for me: https://i.sstatic.net/51jAlPRH.png I've also seen a similar thing on SO and I was under the assumption it was related to the review queue being full (even though, I am "Trusted user" there). Later on the button showed up for me. Seems to be related to something else if it happens on different sites.

@VLAZ Yes, I see the same thing here on MSE: https://i.sstatic.net/gYjeuTAI.png I can see the buttons I refer to at an earlier stage.

@PeterJames right, but in my screenshot the button is missing. It's supposed to be just under the empty tag wiki and it's not. That button (when it exists) is labelled "Create tag info" - it is not the link "help us create it" link.

@VLAZ Here are where I found the two buttons (green circles): https://i.sstatic.net/26WP6wXM.png I don't think I have ever seen the "Create tag info" button.

@PeterJames I'm aware where they are. But they aren't what the post talks about. I showed you an example for the button when it does show up and also that it's missing. If you don't see the "Create tag info" button yourself, then that suggests the post is correct and it indeed doesn't show up. Which is probably more of a bug than a feature request but still.

@RobertLongson because a tag wiki already exists

@RobertLongson https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/car-loan/info - no button for me  https://i.sstatic.net/Ts1jNwJj.png
